# Change umbraco email regex

Tags: regex, umbraco

I want to change my umbraco email regex, because the one that umbraco has as standard is not accepting 'æøå' and uppercase letters. But i have no clue on where i can replace it. One that can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change following `Data Type` property, in your `Document Type`:

[image]

Bear in mind that this property might look a little bit different if you are not using Umbraco 7, but the principle is the same: enter the required regex to validate the field.